# How to allow user to edit ranges in Protected Excel using EPPlus and c#?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, epplus

I am exporting protected excel sheet using EPPlus in my winform(C#) project. Now I want functionality to allow user to edit ranges in that protected excel sheet using same plugin. 
It would be great if you provide Code snippet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileName = "sample.xlsx";
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet1");

    ws.Protection.IsProtected = true;
    ws.ProtectedRanges.Add("editable", new ExcelAddress("C:N"));
    excel.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn’t work for me. It resulted in allowing editing/sorting but removing protection. I also tried switching around the order of adding the protected range first and then adding protection, but same results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know its very late to reply but may help others. I had a similar issue and was struggling to get sorting and auto-filtering in protected worksheet.

After protecting the worksheet, I have added below two settings that allow sorting and auto-filtering.

```
 ws.Protection.IsProtected = True
 ws.Protection.AllowSort = True
 ws.Protection.AllowAutoFilter = True
```

In my case however the next requirement was to unlock some columns to allow editing, I achieved that using:

```
ws.Column(12).Style.Locked = False
```

If you have a range however you can try something like this:

```
  For Each cell In ws.Cells("B1:C8")
                
                    cell.Style.Locked = False
              
  Next
```